# Indistinguishability proof of an encryption scheme

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, provable-security

Is there any indistinguishability proof (e.g., IND-CPA, IND-CCA, IND-CCA1, IND-CCA2, IND-CKA) based on games that involve breaking the AES security? Usually the proof involve breaking  hard problems like DL, CDH, DDH, BDH.

Comment: Sure, instantiate any PRP/blockcipher based encryption scheme with AES and look at the proof. AES-CBC, AES-CTR, AES-GCM.

Comment: Could you please provide some links or papers. I want to check the security analysis of the encryption scheme where the security proof involve breaking the AES algo as in if an adversary can break our scheme, then an algo C (Challenger) can break the AES security.